# Python OpenCV - Template Matching using the live camera feed frame as input

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, camera

I'm starting on OpenCV again after I've tried it in Android some time ago. Now, I'm trying OpenCV 2 with Python 2. So far, I've been able to use it to get the live camera feed, and on a separate project, I've been able to implement template matching where I'll give a parent image and a small image that exists in the parent image, and match the sub images in the parent image and then output another image that draws a red rectangle on the image matches.

Here is the code for the Template Matching. It's nothing special, it's the same one from the OpenCV Site:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img_rgb = cv2.imread('mario.jpg')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template = cv2.imread('mario_coin.png',0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]
res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.8
loc = np.where( res >= threshold)
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,0,255), 2)
cv2.imwrite('res.png',img_rgb)
```

Then as for my code for the Live Camera Feed, I have this:

```
# import the necessary packages
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
import cv2

# initialize the camera and grab a reference to the raw camera capture
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
camera.framerate = 32
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640, 480))

# allow the camera to warmup
time.sleep(0.1)

# capture frames from the camera
for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
    # grab the raw NumPy array representing the image, then initialize the timestamp
    # and occupied/unoccupied text
    image = frame.array

    # show the frame
    cv2.imshow("Frame", image)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # clear the stream in preparation for the next frame
    rawCapture.truncate(0)

    # if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break
```

And so far, both those code work nicely, independent of one another. What I tried was that I tried to insert the Template Matching code in the part before the Camera Stream Code displays anything.

Here was what I came up with:

```
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import time
import cv2
import numpy as np


# initialize the camera and grab a reference to the raw camera capture
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
camera.framerate = 32
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640, 480))

template = cv2.imread('mario_coin.png', 0)


# allow the camera to warmup
time.sleep(0.1)

# capture frames from the camera
for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr",
                                       use_video_port=True):
    # grab the raw NumPy array representing the image,
    # then initialize the timestamp
    # and occupied/unoccupied text
    image = frame.array

    # we do something here
    # we get the image or something then run some matching
    # if we get a match, we draw a square on it or something
##    img_rbg = cv2.imread('mario.jpg')
    img_rbg = image

##    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)



    w, h = template.shape[::-1]

    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

    threshold = 0.8

    loc = np.where(res >= threshold)

    for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
##        cv2.rectangle(img_rbg, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h),
##                      (0,0,255), 2)
        cv2.rectangle(image, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h),
                      (0,0,255), 2)

##    image = img_rgb


    # show the frame
    cv2.imshow("Frame", image)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # clear the stream in preparation for the next frame
    rawCapture.truncate(0)

    # if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break
```

What I'm trying to do is that instead of the `cv2.imread(sample.png)`, I'm trying to use the image input from the camera and use that in the template matching algorithm that I had earlier.

But what happens is that the camera opens for a second (indicated by the light), then it shuts off and the program halts.

I really don't know what's happening. Does anyone have any leads on how to use the live camera feed as an input in template matching?

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 2 with the v1.3 Camera.

Answer (score 3):

I actually managed to solve it. I forgot that I posted a question here.

```
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import time
import cv2
import numpy as np


# initialize the camera and grab a reference to the raw camera capture
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
camera.framerate = 32
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640, 480))

template = cv2.imread('mario_coin.png', 0)


# allow the camera to warmup
time.sleep(0.1)

# capture frames from the camera
for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr",
                                       use_video_port=True):
    # grab the raw NumPy array representing the image,
    # then initialize the timestamp
    # and occupied/unoccupied text
    image = frame.array

    # we do something here
    # we get the image or something then run some matching
    # if we get a match, we draw a square on it or something
    img_rbg = image

    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


    template = cv2.imread("mario_coin.png", 0)
    w, h = template.shape[::-1]

    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

    threshold = 0.8

    loc = np.where(res >= threshold)

    for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
        cv2.rectangle(image, (pt[1]. pt[0]), (pt[1] + w, pt[0] + h),
                      (0,0,255), 2)

    # show the frame
    cv2.imshow("Frame", img_rbg)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # clear the stream in preparation for the next frame
    rawCapture.truncate(0)

    # if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

I already had the same problem , the issue is the variable **res** 
when you start your script first time **res** is empty so comparing an empty variable in **np.where** function won't work
So you should put an :

- **condition** (if res :)
- or an **exception** (try : ... except:)

I Don't have my Pi right now , So this is the same example with laptop camera and opencv :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

name = 'find.png' 
template = cv2.imread(name,0)
face_w, face_h = template.shape[::-1]

cv2.namedWindow('image')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

threshold = 1
ret = True

while ret :
    ret, img = cap.read()

    #flip the image  ! optional 
    img = cv2.flip(img,1)

    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

    if len(res):
        location = np.where( res >= threshold)
        for i in zip(*location[::-1]):
            #puting  rectangle on recognized erea 
            cv2.rectangle(img, pt, (pt[0] + face_w, pt[1] + face_h), (0,0,255), 2)

    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```